# Visual Studio 2015 Intellisense Completion Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, code-completion

In VS2013, when I type "convert.toi", the editor suggests me these:

[image: VS 2013 Suggestions]

Likewise, when I try it in VS 2015, I face like as these suggestions:

[image: VS 2015 Suggestions]

I don't want to type uppercase "I" when I coding. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this.

[Intellisense Case Sensitive Bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1641654/intellisense-case-sensitive-bug)

It was a bug and fixed Update 1 for VS 2015. I installed this update and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I use visual studio 2015 and i am getting correct intelligence
[image]

Try resetting all settings.

Tools->Import and Export settings->Reset all settings.